# Source for fundamental reduction theorem’s proof

Tags: proof-explanation, online-resources

Initally I was looking for chromatic polynomial, but everywhere I look, I see “using the fundamental reduction theorem” and no proof of them! Sorry if the proof is easy to find (or it’s supposed to be extremely intuitive), but my google searches are turning up nothing, just use cases.

Comment: This [link](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m4408/gtln6.htm) might be useful.

Comment: Again, the link only provides use cases, not logical, step-by-step proof

Comment: I guess I'm out of my depth. I thought stuff like [this](http://garsia.math.yorku.ca/~zabrocki/math3260w03/hw4sln.pdf) was proof. Good luck in your search.